# Having trouble referencing object in EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have an object that I am passing into my template using EJS and I continue to get an error saying `Cannot read property 'link' of undefined`, here is the object and here is the template code.

I console.log the object and get this:

```
{ _id: 583e4b76f1c8771c17d68ef2,
  username: 'asdf',
  __v: 0,
  favoriteMoments: [],
  favoriteEvents: [],
  likes: [],
  friends: [],
  moments: [],
  categories: [],
  events: 
   [ { _id: 583e4bf8cc11c61c2887aa38,
       title: 'asdfasdf',
       description: 'asdf',
       __v: 0,
       comments: [],
       photos: [Object],
       moments: [],
       category: [Object],
       owner: [Object] } 
] }
```

Here is the template:

```
        <div class="well event_list_page_event_boxes masonry_box">
            <div class="img-responsive">
               <a href="/event/<%= events._id %>">
                   <% if (events.photos.link === null){%>
                   <div class="event_list_page_event_photo"><p>No Image Here</p></div>
                   <% } else {%>
                   <img class="event_list_page_event_photo" src="<%= events.photos.link %>" border="0" style="max-width: 100%">

                   <% } %>
                   <%}) %>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <h4 class="event_list_page_event_header"><%= events.title %></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <p class="event_list_page_event_date"><%= events.date %></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="event_list_page_event_description"><%= events.description %> </p>
               </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I understand that it is not seeing the `events.photos` object however I am unsure how to make it visible so I can display my data.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you are using to pass in the events object?

Comment: print events array so that you will come to know its structure and you can resolve issue

Answer (score 1):

`events` is an array so instead of this:

```
events.photos.link
```

you would need to use an array index such as:

```
events[0].photos.link
```

Or, you would need to iterate the `events` array.

---

If you are trying to create a new HTML block for each event in the `events` array, then you will need to use some sort of loop in your template (such as a `for` loop or a `.forEach()` loop) so you can loop through each element of the array.

There's an ejs example of a `for` loop in the Create Template section of this article: http://www.embeddedjs.com/getting_started.html

Comment: I would need to iterate through the array, isnt that what `object.keys` is supposed to do?

Comment: @illcrx - `Object.keys()` gets all the properties of an object.  It is generally not used on arrays.  We can't help you further without knowing what you're actually trying to accomplish.  Your question does not describe that.

Comment: Ok so your saying I am using an object call on an array, oooohhh. What I am trying to do is show all of the `events` properties on the template. In the first code snippet you see an `events` key, that will list all of the events, the example only has one event. There will be many events.

Comment: Could I just make this an object and be done with it? Can I have an object of objects with no keys? I really dont want any keys, it should just iterate through the events.

Comment: @illcrx - If you want your template to iterate through the events, creating a new block for each event, then use a `for` loop in your template.  Example here: http://www.embeddedjs.com/getting_started.html in the Create a template section.  Again - your question does not say what you are trying to accomplish (what output you want to achieve) so we can't help you further.

Comment: What needs to happen is that all the event details are displayed on the page, I dont know how else to explain it? Iterate through the objects and each objects details should display on the page. 
I'll check out that link, thanks.

Comment: @illcrx - Please edit your question to say what the desired output should be.  As it stands now, your question speaks only of a problem, not the desired output.  You will need to use something like a `for` loop in that example I linked.

Comment: Ok, thank you I did the for loop in my code, then for some reason I am getting another non-related error....sigh.